# java.util.zip.ZipException in Android project

Tags: java, android

If I import(I use Android Studio, Gradle) in android project jars I have got this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.> 
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/sun/jersey/api/client/AbstractClientRequestAdapter.class
```

I think the problem is that the two JARs contain class AbstractClientRequestAdapter.
Dependencies in my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile project(':jersey-bundle-1.13-b01')
    compile project(':jersey-client-1.19(2)')
    compile project(':jersey-core-1.19(2)')
    compile project(':jersey-multipart-1.19')
    compile project(':org.apache.servicemix.specs.jsr311-api-1.0-1.3.0')
}
```

How I can exclude this class from my project?

Comment: duplicate entry happen

Comment: use one .jersey-client-1.19(2),jersey-core-1.19(2)

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya, they are in one copy, it's just a name. Do you now how  exclude this class correctly?